# Unable to print string containing double quotes in GitLab CI YAML

Tags: bash, yaml, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using the [CI Lint tester](https://gitlab.com/ci/lint) to try and figure out how to store an expected JSON result, which I later compare to a `curl` response. Neither of these work:

**Attempt 1**

```
---
  image: ruby:2.1
  script:
  - EXPECT_SERVER_OUTPUT='{"message": "Hello World"}'
```

Fails with:

> did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 4 column 5

**Attempt 2**

```
---
  image: ruby:2.1
  script:
  - EXPECT_SERVER_OUTPUT="{\"message\": \"Hello World\"}"
```

Fails with:

> jobs:script config should be a hash

I've tried using various combinations of `echo` as well, without a working solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use *literal block scalar*<sup>1</sup> style notation and put the variable definition and subsequent script lines on separate lines<sup>2</sup> without worrying about quoting:

```yaml
myjob:
  script:
    - |
      EXPECT_SERVER_OUTPUT='{"message": "Hello World"}'
```

or you can escape the nested double quotes:

```yaml
myjob:
  script:
    - "EXPECT_SERVER_OUTPUT='{\"message\": \"Hello World\"}'"
```

but you may also want to just use [variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables) like:

```yaml
myjob:
  variables:
    EXPECT_SERVER_OUTPUT: '{"message": "Hello World"}'
  script:
    - dothething.sh
```

<sup>Note: variables are by default [expanded](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-the--character-in-cicd-variables) inside variable definitions so take care with any `$` characters inside the variable value (they must be written as `$$` to be literal). This feature can also be [turned off](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#prevent-cicd-variable-expansion).</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/1072229) for an explanation of this and related notation</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>See [this section of the GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands) for more info on multi-line commands</sup>

Comment: You could expand the answer with information about the first example (folded multiline string), it's rather hard to guess what it does the way it is now.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work like this:

```
  script: |
   "EXPECT_SERVER_OUTPUT='{\"message\": \"Hello World\"}'"
   echo $EXPECT_SERVER_OUTPUT
```